# What verb do I use with 関数 to say "write a function?"

Tags: untagged

What verb do I use with 関数 to say "write a function?"  (This is in a computer programming context, btw.)

I've just been saying 書く but I kinda doubt it's correct.  (I'm saying it over chat, and no one is responding to tell me that I'm wrong...so who knows.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`関数を書く` is fine (see [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9D%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8F%E2%80%9D%20%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0) for this phrase), I use this at work regularly. `関数を定義する` is also fine; much of the programming terminology in Japanese is either taken directly from English (`アルゴリズム`, `クラス`, etc.) or a direct translation so you are safe translating from English for a lot of programming stuff.